# Run npm script with optional params

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I want to run a npm script which accepts optional params, and has a fallback for a default values for params that were not passed,

for example:

I have this "example" script defined in my pacakge.json:

```
  "scripts": {
     "example": "echo input"
  },
```

I want to pass in the "input" as a parameter meaning:

If I run `npm run example --input=true` then it'll output `true`

If I run `npm run example` without params then it'll output `false`

I modified my `pacakge.json` to accept the `input` parameter:

```
  "scripts": {
     "example": "echo %npm_config_input%"
  },
```

now when I run `npm run example --input=true` or `npm run example --input=false`
I get 'true' or 'false' respectively, but when I run `npm run example` the result I get is  `%npm_config_input%`.

I want to give the param a default value so that when its not passed in explicitly - the default value will be used, something similar to :

```
  "scripts": {
     "example": "echo %npm_config_input% || 'false'"
  },
```

So that running `npm run example` will result in `'false'`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@naholyr/cross-env package, which supports default values for variables. On top of that, it will make your script OS-agnostic. Here's how:

```json
"scripts": {
    "example": "cross-env INPUT=${npm_config_input:false} npm run _example",
    "_example": "cross-env command $INPUT"
},
```

For a reason yet unknown to me, using `echo` as the `command` will **not** print the variable value. But I'm successfully using this pattern to run `sass` with arguments, and fallback values, if no arguments are passed.